# Capture Symbol USB barcode scanner input

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode, barcode-scanner

I've been searching everywhere for a solution to capture the input from my Symbol USB barcode scanner without having focus on a particular textbox control.  I've installed the Windows SDK from Motorola and still haven't had any success.
Here's my situation.  I have a form that allows the user to have either a grid view or a form view.  I don't want to have to have the user put the cursor into a particular cell or textbox in order to capture the scan.  I want to be able to have the user just scan the code and I'll programmatically put the information in the cell or textbox that it belongs to.
Thanks in advance,
Bill

Comment: wireshark can capture usb.

Comment: Is there a specific event that ocurrs when a barcode is scanned?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your USB scanner it is possibly acting as a keyboard wedge.  What happens if you are in a text box and perform a scan? Do characters get inserted into the text box?  If they do then simply set up an event on the form that captures keyboard events and then you should be able to direct them to whichever input control you desire.